# LEFT JOIN 2 Tables USING SUM & GROUP BY

Tags: c#, sql

Here are my tables:

```
Table: Catalog                  Table: Inventory
--------------                  ----------------
catalogId      - int [PK]       inventoryId        - int [PK]  
itemName      - nvarchar        inventoryTimeStamp - datetime
itemType      - bit             quantity           - float
catalogNumber - int             catId              - int [FK]
```

My question is:
How do I join the tables (left join them) & summing the quantity of an item in the inventory table, so I could print the: itemName, catalogNumber & sum.

I tried this:

```
SELECT Catalog.itemName, Inventory.catId, SUM(Inventory.quantity) AS Sum
FROM Catalog
LEFT JOIN Inventory ON Inventory.catId = Catalog.catalogId
GROUP BY Inventory.catId
```

But I get an exception:

> Column 'Catalog.itemName' is invalid in the select list because it is
>   not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

What should I do?

Comment: Put the `Catalog.itemName` in the `group by` clause just like the error message says.

Comment: Great! Now, go accept one of the answers below as solving your problem. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add all the non-aggregated columns to the `GROUP BY` clause,

```
SELECT Catalog.itemName, 
       Inventory.catId, 
       SUM(Inventory.quantity) AS Sum 
FROM   Catalog 
       LEFT JOIN Inventory 
           ON Inventory.catId = Catalog.catalogId 
GROUP  BY Catalog.itemName, Inventory.catId
```

Comment: @mellamokb i forgot to delete `enumrate`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add

`GROUP BY Catalog.itemName, Inventory.catId, Inventory.quantity`

and it will work.

When you have `sum`, `count` etc, you need to add a `GROUP BY` at the end of the query

Answer (score 0):

You will need to either remove `Catalog.itemName` from your `SELECT` or include it in your `Group By` clause.